# How do we get the url typed in the browser in the server files?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, url, window.location

How do we get the url that we have typed in the browser in the server side (server files) in javascript? The web framework I am using is React. I cannot use `window.location.href` as window object can only be used in the browser side.

Comment: too broad, umm in the `req` object

Comment: This is very broad, as mentioned. try `document.window.location.href`

Answer (score 0):

window is a browser API it doesn't exist on node, but what you can do is send the window.location.href to the server with a POST request.